# Ghostscript convert PDF into large TIFF

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, ghostscript, pdf-conversion

I want to resize a PDF into TIFF format with Ghostscript.
We use as input PDF/X-3 which has a limitation of 5 meters in length or height.

As a result, I want to have tiff - File with correct dimensions and a final resolution of 200DPI

By scaling this to a bigger format like bigtiff (e.g):

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiff32nc -dNumRenderingThreads=6 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
   -dPDFFitPage -r2000 -dUseCropBox -dUseBigTiff       \
   -sOutputFile=example.tiff test.pdf
```

***Edit from here: My first result is a 2000 dpi file***

Just as trick to scale it to the correct pixels, I then change it to 200DPI with exiftool:

```
exiftool -ResolutionUnit="inch" -xResolution="200" -yResolution="200" example.tiff
```

I do then have a resulting tiff with 200 DPI and dimension of 72/200 times the format I expect.

To be sure my result has the real expected format I then convert it to the calculated format:

```
convert example.tiff -depth 8 -resize 70866x15748\! temp-1.tiff
```

Would that be best suitable way to achieve the goal?

Basics steps are:

1. Convert the image resolution to final dimension
2. Resize it to the target dimension and the final resolution of 200 DPI

EDIT 1: 
The goal is to scale an image by factor with optimum results. The problem is, that customers deliver there data as PDF and want a file printed 10x that big. So we have to scale it to that dimensions. Factor 10 is the maximum we do here. 
E.G. The customer wants a banner to be printed 6m width by 2m height. The file they mostly deliver is in a vector format 600mm by 200mm.
 So I try to scale them to the correct dimensions in a batch process.

EDIT 2: 
I updated the question to the actual status

Comment: *"It also seems to result in a loss of quality"*. What is the output of `identify -ping /tmp/temp-1.tiff ` ??

Comment: It produces `/tmp/temp-1.temp.tiff TIFF 70866x15748 70866x15748+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 39.39MB 0.000u 0:00.030` which is correct by DPI of 200. Still the quality is not the best here.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to create a `708662` pixels wide and `157480` pixels high TIFF is crazy!

A little bit of calculation should tell you that these are **~104 GigaPixels**!

Given that you also requested `tiff32nc` output, this requires 32 bits (4 Bytes) per Pixel (8 bits for each of the requested CMYK channels).

***Do you even have 416 GigaByte of harddisk space on that system, let alone 416 GigaByte of RAM?!?*** (I'm hoping you are not on a 32bit system...) ***How do you intend to handle that file for further processing if you indeed succeed to generate it?!? Which graphic/image processing software will even start to open it?!?***

---

In short: I'm not at all surprised you're running into problems when trying to get Ghostscript to produce such a monster!

<sub>(Also: Do not use `-rXXX` when you also use `-gNNNxMMM`. `-gNNNxMMM` does already set the absolute image dimensions in pixels -- setting `-rXXX` at the same time is useless.)</sub>

<sub>(Yes, I know: TIFFs are typically compressed. So my example calculation above was misleading. On purpose... However, when reading a compressed TIFF from disk, it has to be expanded in memory in order to render it....)</sub>

Comment: Quick calculation shows that 708662x157480 pixels at 2000 dpi results in an image 354 inches in width and 78 inches high. While its not unheard of for signage to that large (or larger) nobody renders signs at 2000 dpi, that's up at coffee table glossy artwork book type resolutions. Perhaps CiTNOH could explain what he's trying to achieve and we could help better.

Comment: I know it sounds like overkill in first place, but the goal is to scale an image by factor 10 with optimum results. The problem is, that customers deliver there data as PDF and want a file printed 10x that big. So we have to scale it to that dimensions. Factor 10 is the maximum we do here. 
I updated my question to my current state